# How to assign a label to a specific cell?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

Right now, when I slide left on the cell to show a "favorite" button and click on it, a label "Favorite" appears on a random cell instead of the one I swiped on. How do I make the "Favorite" label appear/disappear on the right cell when I tap on the designated button?

Right now my code in editActionsForRowAt function is:

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Favorite") { action, index in
        cell.favoriteLabel.text = "Favorite"
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
    favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    return [favorite]
}
```

The problem is setting "favoriteLabel" = "Favorite" doesn't set the "favoriteLabel" of the right cell to "Favorite"

Comment: **Never ever** create a reusable cell outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Update the model (the data source array) and reload the row or the entire table view.

Comment: @vadian how do I make sure it's updating the right cell though (this is my problem) Also, how else can I access my "favoriteLabel" if my cell is created in another function?

Comment: Use the `cellForRow(at:)` method instead of `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`

Comment: Try to understand the model-view-controller pattern. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the cell (**view**) is created and the `text` of `favoriteLabel` is set from the appropriate item in the data source array (**model**). So change the value (**controller**) in the data source array (you got the index path) and reload the row.

Comment: @rmaddy Only updating the cell will not change the model and the label will be overwritten when the user scrolls (`reloadRows` does that anyway).

Comment: @vadian Is there a better way to have a resulted action after the button is pressed than to just put words into a label? like how apple has an orange circle pop up if you click "Flag" in the mail app??

Comment: Of course, you can design a custom cell with custom UI elements. Create a boolean property `favorite` in your model and set an image, animation or whatever you like to on or off depending on that boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the wrong approach here. Instead of directly updating the cell, you should be updating your data model and then reloading the cell at the index path. Then your `cellForRowAt` will properly display the updated cell based on the updated data model.

You actually have a strange mix of the two. You (incorrectly) attempt to get the cell, then set its label, and then reload that row. Don't do both. Simply update your data model and then reload the row. That's it.

As an aside, never call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt:`. If you insist on your current approach (which probably won't work properly after scrolling), you need to replace the call to `dequeueReusableCell` with a call to `cellForRow(at:)`.

Comment: Thank you! That cleared up the comments a bit. Will try the first approach

Comment: what exactly do you mean by my "data model"?

Comment: The data used by your table view's data source to populate the table. Your array (or whatever data) you use in your `cellForRowAt` and `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: how do I make it disappear if the user clicks a row that has already been favorited

Comment: Same way. You update the data model and reload the row.